# How to change the color of non-transparent parts of a PNG file with Slider UI in Spark AR

Tags: spark-ar-studio

In Spark AR Studio I've set a texture to a rectangle, which is a transparent PNG with some text on it. I've applied this texture to a rectangle and have put it in the scene. What I'm trying to achieve here is to use a native Slider UI element to change the non-transparent parts of this PNG which is the "Hello World" obviously.

[image]

The best related article I could find is from their own docs: [Adding a Color Filter](https://sparkar.facebook.com/ar-studio/learn/tutorials/color-filters) which does the steps below:

1. Imports the texture in patch editor
2. Pipes in the RGB output into a color space patch and converts the color space into HSL mode
3. Unpacks the HSL values
4. Modifies the values somehow
5. Packs them again, converts back the color mode into RGB and adds an alpha value.
6. And finally pipes in the output (modified color values) into the material texture which is controlled  as a patch

Here's my setup which is not working, and makes the whole rectangle black instead of changing the non-transparent parts of the texture.
[image]

Any ideas on how to fix this? I know I haven't added the slider UI element to my patch editor yet, at this point I'm playing around with the values in Orange groups. If that works I'm gonna let an slider, control those values.

Answer (score 0):

From what I'm trying to understand, you want to change the "Hello world" to different colors using the Slider UI?

1. Have the rectangle's material texture in the patch editor by selecting the arrow.
2. Drag and drop your "Hello World" texture into the patch editor
3. Import the Adjust colors shader from the AR Library
4. In your patch editor, right-click and search for "Slider UI" and insert (Only works for Instagram thus go to "project" on your toolbar --> "Edit missing properties" and uncheck "Facebook")
5. Connect your "Hello world" Texture RGBA output to the texture input in the Adjust Colors Shader
6. Connect your "Slider UI" output to the "Hue" input in the Adjust Colors Shader
7. Connect your Adjust Colors Shader Output to the material "Diffuse Texture"

[Click to see how your patch editor should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSoTj.png)

Maybe it's just your preference but I would change the "Hello World" to black & white to make it more visible as I change the colors (I use Photoshop to desaturate but any editor that works is fine)